# Changing the y-axis scale in nvd3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am very new to nvd3. **I plot a line chart, where most of the points are in the the Y-axis range 99 to 101. Only a few value will be outside this range.** Check this image:

[image]

**I want this range to be enlarged all the time. I want end users to focus on the range from 99 to 101, regardless of a big or small values as outliers. Basically, the focus should be on the range from 99 to 101, but the other datapoints should also be displayed.**

This is my current code:

```
$scope.setChartType = function(type) {
      console.log(type);
      $scope.options.chart.type = type;
    };
    $scope.options = {
      chart: {
        type: 'lineChart',
        height: ClickHandlerService.chartOptions.height,
        margin: ClickHandlerService.chartOptions.margin,
        x: function (d) {
          return parseInt(d.timestamp);
        },
        y: function (d) {
          return d.latency;
        },
        useInteractiveGuideline: true,
        staggerLabels: true,
        stacked: false,

        transitionDuration: ClickHandlerService.chartOptions.transitionDuration,
        transitionEase: ClickHandlerService.chartOptions.transitionEase,
        dispatch: {
          stateChange: function (e) { /*Placeholder for graph events*/
          },
          changeState: function (e) { /*Placeholder for graph events*/
          },
          tooltipShow: function (e) { /*Placeholder for graph events*/
          },
          tooltipHide: function (e) { /*Placeholder for graph events*/
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
          tickFormat: function (d) {
            return moment(d * 1000).utcOffset(-8).add(1, 'hours').format('DD-MM-YYYY/HH');
          },
          showMaxMin: false
        },
        yAxis: {
          axisLabel: 'Data Latency (In minutes)',
          tickFormat: function (d) {
            return d3.format('.02f')(d);
          },
          axisLabelDistance: 30,
          showMaxMin: false
        },
        callback: function (chart) {
        }
      },
      title: {
        enable: true,
        text: graphDetails.name
      },
      caption: {
        enable: true,
        html: ClickHandlerService.chartOptions.dataLatencyCaption,
        css: ClickHandlerService.chartOptions.captionCss
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `chart.yDomain` to `[99-101]` (or whatever range you want).

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kPjzZM9i2YCjElYG4Imf?p=preview).

Comment: But I want to display the other data points also (which are outside this domain). But the focus should be on the range from 99 to 101.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Do you have an example (picture)?

Comment: I want [99-101] range to be enlarged all the time. I want end users to focus on the range from 99 to 101, regardless of a big or small values as outliers. Basically, the focus should be on the range from 99 to 101, but the other data points MUST also be displayed. I think if we set yDomain to  [99-101], then other data points will not be shown.

Comment: I agree, it is not a solution because it is not showing all the data. I think the solution for this would be a rebuilding of the scale y. There should be a way to do that, although I can't find it. The only two solutions that I have on mind is rebuild the value Y with something like ==> y - min(y) / max(y) - min(y) * n  or  anything in pure nvd3 or d3 to allow us to do a new scale Y