# Draw one chart on the scale of another in NVD3

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js, scaling

I have a chart that is made by `nvd3` library:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/scatterChart.html

that looks like this:

[image]

I want to draw other charts with colored regions separately on the same scale as the overall chart. So, that, say, the orange-colored region would be shown on another chart without any other colored regions. I suppose I would need to get the scaling of the chart with all of the colored regions included and feed it into each of the individual ones. I basically want to avoid re-scaling by setting up the initial scale. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

---

**Update:**

I tried to use the approach proposed in the answer to just set colors of all other clusters to `white` or `transparent` and leave only the needed colored region, but I was not able to achieve this due to another issue that I also asked: [React component instantiation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780277/react-component-instantiation-issue)

So, I tried to dig into `nvd3` `scatterChart` code since we can click on the legend circles and the respective colored region disappears. So, definitely by invoking some specific `nvd3` `scatterChart` functions we can make the regions disappear without much of newly written code, but I have a hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple. Here is the code:

```
...
if (this.props.type === "marker") {
      const domainX = [-174, 172];
      const domainY = [169, -184];
      chart.xDomain(domainX);
      chart.yDomain(domainY);
    }
    d3.select(node)
        .datum(data_func)
        .call(chart);
...
```

I just needed to use `chart.xDomain` and `chart.yDomain` functions. The following thread answered my question:

[Changing the y-axis scale in nvd3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112788/changing-the-y-axis-scale-in-nvd3)

Answer (score 1):

What if you draw the exact same chart but change the color of all regions, but one, to transparent or white?

Comment: This is too complex in my case, I can not do that.